# Disable Segments in a UISegmented Control

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I have 9 Segmented Controls, each with 3 Segments.
I have selected Segment 3 on all of them, and now want to disable the first 2 segments on each of them.
Code so far is as below, what changes do I need to make?

```
    [q2SegControl, q3SegControl, q4SegControl, q5SegControl, q6SegControl, q7SegControl, q8SegControl, q9SegControl, q10SegControl].forEach {
            segmentedControl.setEnabled=false,forSegmentAt:0,1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have to use it like this:

```
[q2SegControl, q3SegControl, q4SegControl, q5SegControl, q6SegControl, q7SegControl, q8SegControl, q9SegControl, q10SegControl].forEach { segmentedControl in
    segmentedControl.setEnabled(false, forSegmentAt: 0)
    segmentedControl.setEnabled(false, forSegmentAt: 1)
 }
```